# Error for [TableItem] is not convertible to () error in swift with array

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array where I'm trying to flatten a set of menu_headers that looks like this (and based upon the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761903/152825):

```
  func processAsList(){
    println("about to process as list")
    var tmpItems:[TableItem] = [EKMenuHeader(), EKMenuItem()]

    for menuHeader in self.menuHeaders {
      println("name #1: \(menuHeader.name)")
      tmpItems.append(menuHeader)
      for menuHeader1 in menuHeader.menuHeaders {
        println("name #2: \(menuHeader1.name)")
        tmpItems.append(menuHeader1)
      }
    }
    return tmpItems
  }
```

but get an error that `[TableItem] is not convertible to '()'`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really just a matter of speaking elementary Swift. You have declared a function:

```
func processAsList(){
```

That declaration means, among other things: "This function returns no value". Therefore, you may not say the words `return tmpItems`, as you are trying to do.

If your function returns something, you must declare that fact, up front:

```
func processAsList() -> SomeKindOfValue {
```

It looks to me like in your case that would be

```
func processAsList() -> [TableItem] {
```

Comment: ah thx, ended up putting my head on the desk after I wrote that question - I'm so tired. Thx for the thorough response! Might need to read a good book on Swift / iOS

Comment: Funny you should mention that: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch02.html#_function_parameters_and_return_value