# Google Mobile Native Express ads iOS - Issues with [AnyObject]

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, anyobject

I'm trying to implement Native Express Ads in my iOS Project, with swift.

First of all I have a class

```
class Events {
  var _eventName: String!
  var _realDate: Date!

    var realDate: Date {
        if _realDate == nil {
            _realDate = nil
        }
        return _realDate
    }

    var eventName: String {
        if _eventName == nil {
            _eventName = ""
        }
        return _eventName
    }

//...
}
```

Which class is getting a JSON from internet and it fills out a tableview.
Also i have some functions with this like Searching through the names of the events and also i have a button that filters events by date.
All these are working fine with the code below

```
var eventData = [Events]()
var filteredEvents = [Events]()

eventData.sort() { $0.realDate < $1.realDate }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        filteredEvents = eventData.filter { events in
            return events.eventName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
```

So While i followed the example of the native express ads from [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/master/Swift/advanced/NativeExpressTableViewExample/NativeExpressTableViewExample/TableViewController.swift) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chNb7-k6m4M)

First of all i changed

```
var eventData = [Events]()
var filteredEvents = [Events]()
```

to

```
var eventData = [AnyObject]()
var filteredEvents = [AnyObject]()
```

So the ads can be appended to the array as i show below in the function `addNativeExpressAds()`!
I have issues with the functions `sort()` and the `filter`.

for the `sort()` it says `Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'realDate'`

and for `filter` it says `Value of type 'AnyObject' has no member 'eventName'`

Update 1. 
After some research on google i found out this could be a solution for `sort()` function

```
eventData.sort() { (($0 as! Events).realDate ) < ($1 as! Events).realDate }
```

Although the `eventData` Array also includes `GADNativeExpressAdView` since in the example that i have linked above there is this block of code that downloads the express native ads and appends them to the `AnyObject` Array `eventData` see below

```
func addNativeExpressAds() {
    var index = adInterval
    // Ensure subview layout has been performed before accessing subview sizes.
    nearMeTable.layoutIfNeeded()
    while index < eventData.count {
        let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(
            CGSize(width: nearMeTable.contentSize.width, height: adViewHeight))
        guard let adView = GADNativeExpressAdView(adSize: adSize) else {
            print("GADNativeExpressAdView failed to initialize at index \(index)")
            return
        }
        adView.adUnitID = adUnitID
        adView.rootViewController = self
        adView.delegate = self


        eventData.insert(adView, at: index) //here it inserts the ads
        adsToLoad.append(adView)
        loadStateForAds[adView] = false

        index += adInterval
    }
}
```

and by this I get the error

```
Could not cast value of type 'GADNativeExpressAdView' (0x10046ebd8) to 'Events_Near_Me.Events' (0x10046fb90).
```

So i can't sort the array of any object cause the `GADNativeExpressAdView` ads inside my array.

Any idea about this one?

Comment: Not related but properties with backing instance variables to get constants is ridiculous in Swift. Just write `let realDate: Date, let eventName: String` and **write an initializer**. Second of all: If you want to combine two different types in an array, write a protocol that both types conform to and use the protocol as type rather than `AnyObject` which is always the worse way.

Comment: @vadian hey! there is an initilizer although I didn't write down the whole `class`. About the `Protocol` could you give me an example if you can?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no information how `GADNativeExpressAdView` and `Events` are related.

Comment: @vadian if its the worst way  to proceed making the array as `AnyObjects` why Google says in their example to do so... I've asked them at their groupd and they don't answer... too bad

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761903/3687801) or [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32975891/3687801) might help you.

Comment: Maybe the Google guys translated their code literally form Objective-C to Swift without taking advantage of the Swift special features. The weird backing instance variables look pretty much like *google translate* ;-)

Comment: Google translate!!! LOL @vadian

Comment: @nayem those examples that you sended, they have the same type of variable inside their class. In my case, GADNativeExpressAdView has no date !

Comment: Yes I know. But I just tried to show you alternatives. One of them ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761903/3687801)) implements `protocol` that was suggested by vadian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in your `sort` function you force a cast `!` to an `Event` type but your array does not only contain `Event` object only. So you force the cast and your code fails.

```
eventData.sort { (first, second) in  
    if let first = first as? Event,
        let second = second as? Event {
        return first.realDate < second.realDate
    }
    if let fist = first as? GADNativeExpressAdView,
        let second = second as? GADNativeExpressAdView {
        return \\ compare?
    }

    return false
}
```

This is a sample code, I haven't tested it to see if it works as expected but it should give you an idea on how to proceed.

P.S. I do not think it is a good practice to mix your data with views. You should keep your array clean of views and have it only contain data.