# What's the point of conforming to an empty protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm just working on a codebase where the most classes conform to an empty protocol. Is there any point of doing so? Actually conforming that protocol does nothing.

Edit as reaction to @vacawama's helpful comment : the protocol is only used once

```
import Foundation

protocol myUrlRequestConfig {}

extension myUrlRequest: myUrlRequestConfig {
    public static func configGetAppConfig() -> URLRequest {
        let request = ....
        return request
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple classes/structs that conform to the empty protocol it allows you to treat them as one type such as putting them all in the same array. For example https://stackoverflow.com/a/30761903/1630618

Comment: @vacawama, yeah that's how I've seen it used too. Sometimes seems like Swift could use a change to the language in that area to make that unnecessary, but ... maybe not. Anyway, great answer.

Comment: @vacawama thanks for your comment, that makes sense. But in the the code here the protocol is used only once.

Comment: It is Swift naming convention to name all your protocols and types starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: The protocol in your example is pointless because – as you said – it does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our app has three perfectly legitimate uses for an empty protocol:

- The protocol has an extension with method definitions. The implementation in the extension is automatically injected into any type that adopts the protocol.
- The protocol has other protocols that adopt it. This allows multiple protocols to be unified under a single head.
- The protocol marks the adopter as wanting some other type to behave in a certain way. Code can always check whether an object `is ThisEmptyProtocol` and if it is, can behave differently than if it isn't.

Comment: Especially the third point is enlightening!

Answer (score 3):

An empty protocol can be useful if you want to create an easy way to add static functions or variables to several different classes. Of course, this only makes sense if the static functionality is the same for all classes conforming to the protocol.

Here is an example: I have a protocol sizeable. Every class that conforms to Sizeable is extended with the static variable stride and size.

```
protocol Sizeable { }

extension Sizeable {
    static var size: Int {
        return MemoryLayout<Self>.size
    }

    static var stride: Int {
        return MemoryLayout<Self>.stride
    }
}

class Foo: Sizeable {}

class Baa: Sizeable {}
```

```
Foo.size
Baa.size
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can't call a static property on an instance of its type. You need to call in on the type itself `Foo.size`

Comment: Regarding using an empty protocol, I wouldn't recommend that. You should add the required properties there and mark them as static. `protocol Sizeable {
    static var size: Int { get }
    static var stride: Int { get }
}`

Comment: I would agree with you if different classes have different implementations of the same property, but in my example the implementation of the property is the same for all classes that conform to the protocol.

Comment: But a protocol is a contract. It would require you to implement it someway